# How to add mi-slider to Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this pretty neat slider, and would love to have it work in some way or another with bootstrap. Can I simply add it or does it require a lot of customization?

It is really easy to use and looks good on any site and automatically resizes ect so I am not to sure what to do with it.

I don't want to start playing with it if there is a simply way or alternative out there?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>test</title>
            <meta name="Description" content="Test"/>
            <meta name="Keywords" content="Test"/>
            <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider.css" />
            <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Luckiest+Guy|Quicksand:300|Asap:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Roboto|Signika:700" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"><h4>slasssgs</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"><h4>Oxforssds</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"><h4>Loafesssrs</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04"><h4>Sneaksssers</h4></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"><h4>slasg</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06"><h4>Hassts &amp; Caps</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07"><h4>Sunglassssssses</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08"><h4>Scssarves</h4></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09"><h4>ssssss</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10"><h4>Luxury</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11"><h4>Sport</h4></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="img12"><h4>sssss</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="img13"><h4>Duffel Bags</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg" alt="img14"><h4>Laptossssssp Bags</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg" alt="img15"><h4>Briefsssscases</h4></a></li>
                </ul>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#">Limos</a>
                    <a href="#">Coaches</a>
                    <a href="#">Minibuses</a>
                    <a href="#">Executive cars</a>


                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>




        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.catslider.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();
                });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap comes with a slider class, but you can use your own. I would only say be wary of doubling the jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the bootstrap libraries in your `html` head and at the bottom of your `body`

Bootstrap pages usually look like the example in the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text-css">
    .example {
      min-height: 400px;
      background-color: #333333;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 example">
            <p>This is column 1</p>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 example">
            <p>This is column 2</p>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 example">
            <p>This is column 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

And the Bootstrap template is based on the 12-grid, so every row has a maximum of 12 columns (as default). For YOUR purposes, you can put your code inside the `container-fluid`, place the jquery library link on the bottom, and it would work.